# Adding multiple local fonts to NextJs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fonts, next.js13

I'm trying to add multiple local fonts to nextjs 13.
The [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization#local-fonts) says to do the following for a single file.

I tried importing the two files in the following way:

```
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import localFont from '@next/font/local';
const myFonts = localFont({
  src: '../public/Fonts/AnultraSlabRegular.ttf',
  variable: '--Anultra-Slab',
});
const myFonts2 = localFont({
  src: '../public/Fonts/IntroRegular.ttf',
  variable: '--Intro-Regular',
});
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={'${myFonts2.className} ${myFonts.className}'}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

this method did not work when assigning a font-family to specific elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code is in the _app.js file
&
i'm using backticks inside the classname

Comment: any luck? have the same q

Answer (score 7):

I had to read the [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/optimizing/fonts#with-tailwind-css) more than once. (Since it is referencing the variable name in the example using Google fonts.) It took me quite some time to only discover adding multiple classes should not be done by using the className (as most examples use) to apply one font like;

```js
// Do not use className for importing multiple local fonts
<body className={`bg-black ${nantes.className} ${spezia.className}`}>
  {children}
</body>
```

But by using the variable name like this;

```js
// use variable for importing multiple fonts which you can use throughout the application
<body className={`bg-black ${nantes.variable} ${spezia.variable}`}>
  {children}
</body>
```

To be complete, this is what I have right now, which works;

layout.tsx

```js
import localFont from '@next/font/local'

const spezia = localFont({
  src: '../fonts/FaroVariableWeb.woff2', 
  variable: '--font-spezia'
})
const nantes = localFont({
  src: '../fonts/Nantes_Variable_Upright_Web.woff2', 
  variable: '--font-nantes'
})

import './globals.css'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      {/*
        <head /> will contain the components returned by the nearest parent
        head.tsx. Find out more at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head
      */}
      <head />
      <body className={`bg-black ${nantes.variable} ${spezia.variable}`}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

global.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html, body {
  font-family: var(--font-spezia);
  color:blueviolet;
}

h1 {
  font-family: var(--font-nantes);
  color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot ! They should have mentioned it in a more explicit way... You saved me man !

Comment: Agree with the comment above - this is great. Thank you!

Comment: How would this work with a custom _document using page router?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Tailwind? I see you are defining a variable for the font but not using it here, and there are a [couple of extra steps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization#with-tailwind-css) to get Tailwind wired up.

The only syntax issue I see is the backticks on the class name that you already mentioned.

```
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import localFont from '@next/font/local';
const myFonts = localFont({
  src: '../public/Fonts/AnultraSlabRegular.ttf',
  variable: '--Anultra-Slab',
});
const myFonts2 = localFont({
  src: '../public/Fonts/IntroRegular.ttf',
  variable: '--Intro-Regular',
});
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={`${myFonts2.className} ${myFonts.className}`}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

you can also use the variable you defined in your CSS once you have them loaded. It should look something like:

```
button {
  font-family: var(--Anultra-Slab);
}
```

I had similar issues where the font was being loaded but not applied because a global style was overriding the `font-family` to nothing, making it default to the system font. I expanded `font-family` in the "computed" view in dev tools to find the issue, then added `font-family: inherit` to the offending class to fix it.

You should be able to apply the `font-family: var(--Anultra-Slab)` in the browser dev tools to make sure the font is being loaded correctly, poke around, and locate the issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this easily with nextjs and tailwindCSS.
This is how i did it, I am using one google font and the other is a local font placed inside my public folder. I needed to use multiple font-weights for the same font and they were in the separate files so this is how i loaded em using next local fonts.

I imported the files inside the src:[] for the local font and added all the required fonts inside the array and then i gave it a variable name so it can be used for applying.

After this I added both the fonts to the body tag.

```
// app/layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";
import localFont from "next/font/local";

import DefaultProvider from "@/providers/DefaultProvider";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";

import "./globals.css";

const poppins = Poppins({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
  variable: "--font-poppins",
  weight: ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", 
   "900"],});

  const organetto = localFont({
   src: [
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/organetto/organetto-light-webfont.woff",
      weight: "300",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/organetto/organetto-regular- 
      webfont.woff",
      weight: "400",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/organetto/organetto-extbold- 
       webfont.woff",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },

    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/organetto/organetto-ultrabold- 
      webfont.woff",
      weight: "800",
      style: "normal",
    },
   ],
   variable: "--font-organetto",
 });


 
 export default function RootLayout({
   children,
 }: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }) {
   return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${poppins.variable} ${organetto.variable} `}>
        <Navbar />
        <DefaultProvider>{children}</DefaultProvider>
        <Footer />
      </body>
     </html>
   );
  }
```

after setting this up, you need to update you tailwind.config.ts file as well. you have to add the variable names here that you specified while importing the fonts. after this you can finally use this

```
//tailwind.config.ts
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
     
      screens: {
        "2xl": { max: "1535px" },
        xl: { max: "1279px" },
        lg: { max: "1023px" },
        tab: { max: "991px" },
        mob: { max: "768px" },
      },

      fontFamily: {
        poppins: ["var(--font-poppins)"],
        organetto: ["var(--font-organetto)"],
      },
   
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

After adding it in the tailwind configs you can use it inside the component like this

```
  <p className="font-bold font-organetto">
    Subscribe and save
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tailwind then this is how I did it -
Firstly add the font faces at the top in your root styles file (probably named as either globals.css or style.css):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "IntroRegular";
  src: url("/Fonts/IntroRegular.ttf");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "AnultraSlabRegular";
  src: url("/Fonts/AnultraSlabRegular.ttf");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And then in your tailwind.config.js file, extend the
fontFamily to include your font like this:

```
theme: {
  extend: {
    fontFamily: {
      IntroRegular: ["IntroRegular", "sans-serif"],
      AnultraSlabRegular: ["AnultraSlabRegular", "sans-serif"]
     }
  }
}
```

Now, you can use these fonts just like you use tailwind ones, for example:

```
<main className="font-AnultraSlabRegular">
```